# running rails spec tests on heroku postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

I am trying to use a free heroku postgres instance to use as my test database, but I am running into a problem as the first step seems to be for minitest to drop the database, which heroku postgres doesn't allow instead it allows to purge the database I think.

```
action@clinio2-13639:~/workspace/clinio(master*)$ rake                                                                                                                                                           
    rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"                                                                                                                                                                
    DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
    ......
    Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge                                                                                                                                                                      
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

not sure how to get past this error. And my dev environment I dont have root privlidges so I cant set up a local postgres instance which would obviously be ideal.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you just really need root privileges in a development environment. Heroku is pretty locked down, so it's not ideal for testing. Here are some options:

- Find or buy a cheap machine to use for web development. If you're familiar with Linux (or are open to becoming more familiar), you have a free operating system to install that works really well with rails development. I do all my webdev work in Linux and recommend [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) for newcomers.
- Check out [Nitrous.io](http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/07/02/building-a-rails-4.0-app-on-nitrous-io.html). I haven't used it, but it looks interesting and it seems to have a free option for in-browser web development. I'm not sure if it would provide the kind of environment you need and am not in any way affiliated with the service.

Comment: Hi chris thanks for your input but intact nitrous.io is the dev environment I am using unfortunately no root access. I think I'll just have to move to developing on my local machine if I can't work it through with their support! Thanks for your help though

Comment: Good to know! Not having root access is kind of a deal-breaker, so thanks for the heads up on Nitrous. I just gave you a +1 for answering MY question. :-)

Comment: Hey Chris just thought I should update you. Was just invited to beta test a new package manager being used by nitrous.io called Parts/autoparts (https://github.com/action-io/autoparts). Seems good you can install postgres, mysql, mongodb or redis on the local machine. Seems to take care of my original problems!

Comment: I just ran into this problem again because the Nitrous.io package manager doesn't contain the UUID extension for Postgres. I thought I could just use a Heroku Postgres DB together with Nitrous but now I can't run tests.